# Access attributes of the last object in array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, javascript-objects

I have hit a Vue.js Javascript wall.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Things</h1>
  <div v-for="thing in things">
    <input v-model="thing.val">
  </div>
  <button @click="addThing">
    NewThing
  </button>
  <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    things: [],
    things2: [],
    things3: [],
    things4: []
  },
  methods: {
    addFind: function () {
      this.things.push({ val: '' });
      var l = this.things[this.things.length-1];
      this.things2.push(l);
      this.things3.push(l.val);
      this.things4.push(l["val"]);
    }
  }
});
```

Output for things and things2 is fine and as expected. 
Output for things3 and things4 is not as expected. 
I can't access the "val" key of objects in an array. I am not an expert on Javascript objects, but this should work, right? What am I missing? How do I access "val"?

Output:

```
    {
  "things": [
    {
      "val": "first"
    },
    {
      "val": "second"
    },
    {
      "val": ""
    }
  ],
  "things2": [
    {
      "val": "first"
    },
    {
      "val": "second"
    },
    {
      "val": ""
    }
  ],
  "things3": [
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ]
}
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rcLgmv18/3/

**UPDATE: It is clear now that for some reason there is an object at the end of the array with { val : "" }. I get the desired behavior if I do (length - 2), instead of (length - 1). The question is why is the last object kind of weird with val=""? Is it a Vue.js or a Javascript feature?**

Comment: You *are* accessing the `val` property of the last item of the array. The value of that property is the empty string `""` and that's what's getting pushed to `things3`.

Comment: `this.things` is an array of objects, `l` is the last element of `this.things`, so it's an object of key `val`. `l.val` thus giving an empty string. Seems normal. What are you expecting?

Comment: @thanksd You are the best! Why is the last element empty though? I don't get it...

Comment: @Psidom, I don't think it is the case. Doing length - 2 fixes it, since length -1 is for some reason a null object, something weird like that. Or maybe it isn't a null object, but it has "val" = "". Super weird, and I don't get it.

Comment: Into things1 and things2 you push a reference to the same object literal. Into things3 and things4 you push a new string literal, that happens to be the empty string at the time of creation, and is thus not updated when the original object is updated.

Comment: I now understand the problem better, and I updated the question, which really reads "Why is the last object in the array weird/empty like that"?

Answer (score 0):

I think @JamesWesc has given the best description. I've fiddled a bit, renaming a couple of the variables to more clearly describe what I think you're after...

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    finds: [],
    lastFind: {},
    lastFindVal: ''
  },
  methods: {
    addFind: function () {
      this.finds.push({ val: '' });
      this.lastFind = this.finds[this.finds.length-1];
      this.lastFindVal = typeof this.lastFind.val;
    }
  }
});
```

Which gives me this output when I add two "finds" input boxes, enter 'ab' in the first and 'cd' in the second.

```
{
  "finds": [
    {
      "val": "ab"
    },
    {
      "val": "cd"
    }
  ],
  "lastFind": {
    "val": "cd"
  },
  "lastFindVal": "string"
}
```

I can't quite figure out why I can't get `lastFindVal` to output `"cd"`, but I'm not a Vue developer. You can see that it is a string though, and does appear to be an empty string. Therefore, @JamesWesc seems to be on the right track. Might it have something to do with the framework? IDK